# Angular-Fullstack Deployment to Openshift Error

Tags: gruntjs, openshift, angular-fullstack

I have deployed an angular-fullstack (Yeoman generator) app to Openshift successfully, however, when I make changes and try to push the changes to Openshift via the command "grunt buildcontrol:openshift" I get the following error...

> > Unable to process task.
> >     Warning: Required config property "buildcontrol.openshift" missing. Use --force to continue.

Has anyone come across this error and found a solution? If I try and force the task it does not do anything additional. I'm not quite sure what I need to be looking for, or adding.